# Bubble Chart Legend Overlapping Plot

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, plotly, bubble-chart

I've been working in R-markdown with Plotly to create a dynamic dashboard and ran into an issue where, when I create a bubble chart with a horizontal legend beneath the chart the legend overflows onto the chart when there are too many series.

Unfortunately the number of series are highly variable so I can't just re position the legend statically.  Ideally the legend would still occupy the same space but would have a vertical (or horizontal) scroll bar like the vertical legend.

**Edit: This dashboard is sent out as a self contained html document via email and the data does not update after it is rendered. However it is run unattended ~150 times a day (each for a different end user) which is why the solution needs to be dynamic.**

Reproducible Code: (font size set to 20 to reduce the number of data points needed to cause the error, same error with font size 12 and more elements)

```
percent_new_fills <- 
(c(100,98,97,96,34,35,36,36,37,39,43,56,67,78,3,4,5,6,13,14,15,16,16,14,17))
percent_fills <- (c(35,36,36,37,39,43,56,67,78,100,98,97,96,34,8,3,13,14,15,16,13,18,19,18,11))
volume <- (c(3,4,3,2,5,6,3,2,3,4,5,6,4,3,3,2,1,2,3,4,5,6,5,4,3))
pres_name <- c('PrescriberA','PrescriberB','PrescriberC','PrescriberD','PrescriberE','PrescriberF','PrescriberG','PrescriberH','PrescriberI','PrescriberJ','PrescriberK','PrescriberL','PrescriberM','PrescriberN','PrescriberO','PrescriberP','PrescriberQ','PrescriberR','PrescriberS','PrescriberT','PrescriberU','PrescriberV','PrescriberW','PrescriberX','PrescriberY')
region <- "Orlando"
bubble_data <- data.frame(percent_new_fills,percent_fills,volume,pres_name)

bubble <- plot_ly(bubble_data, x = ~percent_new_fills, y = ~percent_fills,
              type = "scatter",
              mode = "markers",
              sizes = c(5,25),
              color = pres_name,
              colors = "Set3",
              size = volume,
              hoverinfo = 'text',
              text = ~paste(pres_name,
                            '</br>', volume, ' TTRx written',
                            '</br> Fill Rate: ', percent_fills,'%',
                            '</br> % New Fills: ', percent_new_fills,'%',
                            sep = ""))%>%
   layout(xaxis = list(title = "% New Fills", ticksuffix="%"),
     yaxis = list(title = "Fill Rate", ticksuffix="%"),
     legend = list(orientation = 'h',x=0,y=-.2,font=list(size=20)),
     margin = list(r=50))  %>% config(displaylogo = FALSE)
 bubble
```

[Expected Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AsxM5.jpg)

[Bubble chart result with too many series](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlC6e.jpg)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how your dashboard looks like, but you could use jQuery, to move the legend down beneath the title of the x-axis:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  var h =$('text.xtitle').attr('y');
  $('g.legend').attr('transform', 'translate(60,' + h*1.02 +')');
});
</script>
```

We check at what y-coordinate the title of the x-axis is, save that value in `h` and change the transformation of the `g.legend` item accordingly.

Since I do not know where this plot is located on your dashboard (relative to the origin) this might not work as intended. But the idea might help you.

[image]

Comment: Martin, thanks for the help! I forgot a key detail which is that this dashboard is sent out via email as a self-contained .html doc (awful, I know) so I don't know that J-query will work.

I'll edit my original post.

Comment: Ok. I am not sure why the legend moves up anyhow. Seems almost like a bug to me.